# Zend studio show code coverage

Tags: php, phpunit, code-coverage, zend-studio

I have just downloaded zend studio 13.5 and I'm trying to figure out how to see code coverage in the editor.

I did successfully implement my first PHPUnit test and it works fine. When I run the test I do see in the console the results, however I am unable to show code coverage, is there an option I must turn on to see in the editor which lines are covered by my tests?

Answer (score 1):

In order to view Code Coverage, go to Zend Studio | Window | Show View | Code Coverage.